# How to extract float number from data frame string

Tags: pandas, string, floating-point, extract

In my data frame every entry is a string which consists of at least one number. Sometimes there are multiple and identical entries in one cell.

```
data = {'INTERVAL': ['0,60', '0,8 0,8', '0,5 0,5 0,5']}     
df = pd.DataFrame(data)       
print(df)
```

How can I extract the value as floating number and replace the original column with the new simplified representation? I've tried to use the extract

```
df['INTERVAL'].str.extract('((\d+))')
```

command, however I failed.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is the expected ouput?

Comment: If this is the pattern, what about splitting over the whitespace and taking the first one?

Comment: i.e., `df.INTERVAL.str.split(n=1).str[0].str.replace(",", ".", n=1).astype(float)`, where `n=1`'s make the corresponding operations happen at most one for some efficiency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work for me -

```
floats = df['INTERVAL'].str.extract("(^[0-9]*,[0-9]*) ?.*")
df['INTERVAL'] = floats[0].str.replace(",",".").astype(float)
```